# How do I loop threw my mediaPlayer on a delay without having sounds playing over one another?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make an app that will tell the user "Ready Go" it will give the user two seconds to get set up and then a random amount of time after that it will say ready and a random amount of time after that it will say go. I got this part to work but now I want to loop it to where the user only has to press the button once and it'll keep playing. However, when I put it in a loop it'll run through it all at once and it ends up playing all the "Ready Go's" at the same time. Is there something I can do to prevent this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Context context;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;

    public void start (View view) {
        play();
    }

    public void play() {
        //When I put a loop here I will get the audio playing over each other, I 
        //also tried to put it in the start method but I get the same result. Is 
        //there another way I should be going about this? Thanks for the help!

        long range = 2000L;
        Random r = new Random();
        long number = (long) (r.nextDouble() * range);
        long range1 = 1500L;
        Random rand = new Random();
        long number1 = (long) (r.nextDouble() * range);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Info", "Ready");
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }    
        }, 2000 + number);
        Handler handler3 = new Handler();
        handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Info", "Go");
                mediaPlayer1.start();
            }
        }, 2200 + number + number1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CompletionListener instead of loop, First Call playAudio1 method in play(). code is below,

```
mediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playAudio2();
        }
    });


    mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playAudio1();
        }
    });
```

playAudio1 and playAudio2 methods,

```
private void playAudio2() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Info", "Go");
            mediaPlayer1.start();
        }
    }, 2200 + number + number1);
}

private void playAudio1() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Info", "Ready");
            mediaPlayer1.start();
        }
    }, 2000 + number);
}
```

Use mediaPlayer.prepare() or mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() before mediaPlayer.start().

Comment: As @Deˣ said, the setOnCompletionListener part needs to be inside the onCreate method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in onCreate method

```
mediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        play();
      }
    });
```

This will call the `play` method again once it completes the `mediaPlayer1`. playing.

Comment: I tried this and it plays with the loop but it only plays one time, it seems like it's not reading that running is changed to false in handler3 and ending the loop. I tried moving running = false to the end of the play method but that doesn't run at all. Is there something else I could do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried this but now it won't play at all, it seems to be looping but it's not playing the ready go's like it should be. I tried to put the if statement in another handler and delayed it for 6 seconds because it seemed like it wasn't delaying when it went through the play method but that didnt work either. I am also seeing this in the logcat - Queue length for executor EventBus is now 11. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small, and  E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module and W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1.

Comment: @Michael I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Accept the answer so it can help others too.